# $\prod_{k=1}^{n} \Big( k^2 + k \Big)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, products

Consider this product:

$$\beta_{n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \Big( k^2 + k \Big)$$

I have tried applying associativity rule:

$$\beta_{n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \Big(k^2 + k\Big) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + \prod_{k=1}^{n}k = (n!)^2 + n! = n! (n! + 1)$$

For $n = 4$ this produces output $600$. But it should be $2880$.

WolframAlpha gives this as a result: $\beta_{n} = (n!)^2(n+1)$

Hence I assume that associativity rule does not work like it would work with sums.

So how do I go about computing this quite simple product?

Comment: What distributivity law? A product of a sum is not the sum of a product, i.e. $(1^2 + 1)(2^2 + 2) \not= (1^2 + 2^2) + (1+2)$. To solve this write it as $k^2 + k = k(k+1)$ and use that $\prod k(k+1) = \prod k \prod (k+1)$.

Comment: Oops, I meant `associativity rule`, thought it was called `distrubitvity law`.

Comment: Call it that if you will, the name is of little importance. My point was that the rule you seem to use is not valid for products (it only hold for sums).

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful. Now I get the idea how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Winther mentioned in the comments, "a product of a sum is not the sum of a product": You tried to use a formula of the form $\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+b_k)=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\prod_{k=1}^n b_k$, but this is not true even for $n=2$:
$$\prod_{k=1}^2(a_k+b_k)=a_1a_2+a_1b_2+b_1a_2+b_1b_2,\quad\text{whereas}\quad \prod_{k=1}^2a_k+\prod_{k=1}^2 b_k=a_1a_2+b_1b_2.$$

---

In general, for sequences $(a_k)_k$ and $(b_k)_k$, we have
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n a_kb_k
&=(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)\cdots(a_nb_n)\\
&=(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(b_1b_2\cdots b_n)\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n b_k\right)
\end{align*}

We apply this for $a_k=k$, $b_k=k+1$:
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n(k^2+k)&=\prod_{k=1}^nk(k+1)\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(k+1)\right)\\
&=n!(n+1)!\\
&=(n!)^2(n+1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
&\prod_{k=1}^{n} \bigl(k^2 + k \bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&\prod_{k=1}^{n} \bigl(k(k+1)\bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} k\right)\!\!\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&n!{\,\cdot\,}(n+1)!\\[4pt]
=\;&n!{\,\cdot\,}\bigl((n+1){\,\cdot\,}n!\bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&(n+1)(n!)^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
As regards your attempt . . .

To see that your attempted simplification
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \Big(k^2 + k\Big) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + \prod_{k=1}^{n}k$$
is not valid, note that for $n=2$, the LHS evaluates to 
$$(1^2+1)(2^2+2)=(2)(6)=12$$
whereas the RHS evaluates to 
$$(1^2)(2^2)+(1)(2)=4+2=6$$

Answer (score 2):

You can't distribute the product:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a_k+b_k)\ne \prod_{k=1}^na_k+\prod_{k=1}^n b_k.$$
However,
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(a_kb_k)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n b_k\right).$$
That being said, we have
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^nk(k+1)&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n (k+1)\right)\\
&=n!\prod_{k=2}^{n+1} k\\
&=n!(n+1)\prod_{k=2}^{n} k\\
&=n!^2(n+1)
\end{align}$$